# pyspark mllib IndexedRowMatrix type how to get item by indices

Tags: matrix, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

Is it possible to get matrix content from mllib indexedRowMatrix type by providing the coordinate? E.g.

```
rows = sc.parallelize([IndexedRow(0, [1, 2, 3]),IndexedRow(1, [4, 5, 6]),IndexedRow(2, [7, 8, 9]),IndexedRow(3, [10, 11, 12])])
mat = IndexedRowMatrix(rows)
```

If I give the coordinate `(0,1)`, I should get 2 from `mat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark matrices (and distributed containers in general) don't  support random access. It is possible to `filter`:

```py
mat.rows.filter(lambda row: row.index == 0).first().vector[1]
```

but this operations is linear in terms of the number of rows.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson _And my intellisense was not working in jupyter for some reason either_ - there is no type information that could be used to infer type of lambda expression. You could try [this](https://github.com/zero323/pyspark-stubs) but I don't think it will work with Jupyter.